# SQL Server 2012 data conversion

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to perform some data conversion on a table. I am trying to take a value (string) from one table and make give it a corresponding numeric value (int) in the new table.

For instance:

```
Operational = 1
Needs Repair = 2
etc.
```

I can find examples for casting and parsing values into new data types however I can not find examples on how to change the actual value to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CASE statement

```
select 
    case yourfield
        when 'Operational' then 1
        when 'needs Repair' then 2
        .... and so on....
    end AS yourfield
from yourtable
```

Comment: You can also specify a name for the column after end. Just fyi